# getting hours and day difference between two dates in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, date, difference

i am getting two dates as
$date1 = 2020-07-16 03:50:32
$date2 = 2017-01-25 09:43:53

i want to get the difference between thes two dates.
THe difference count hours until 24 hours and then days plus hours.
eg. 2 days and 5 hours.

THe code i tried is this

```
  $createddate = date("d-m-Y H:i:s", strtotime($application['created_at']));
    
     $approvedisapprovedate = date("d-m-Y H:i:s", strtotime($application['approved_at']));
     
     $created = strtotime($createddate);
    $approvedisapprove = strtotime($approvedisapprovedate);
        $diff = $approvedisapprove - $created;
        $days = floor($diff / (60 * 60 * 24));
       $hours = round(($diff - $days * 60 * 60 * 24) / (60 * 60));
```

but it won't work.anybody suggest a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use carbon for this. Carbon can make it simple to manipulate dates very efficiently not for only this task but many other related date.

**Install carbon**

```
{
  "require": {
    "nesbot/carbon": "^1.22"
  }
}
```

**Usage**

```
$date->diffForHumans();
```

OR

```
$date->diffInDays();
```

In your case, you can try below code -

```
$createddate = Carbon::parse($application['created_at']);
$approvedisapprovedate = Carbon::parse($application['approved_at']);

//here is carbon magic
$createddate->diffInDays($approvedisapprovedate); //This will give you diff in number of days.

$createddate->diffForHumans($approvedisapprovedate); //This will give you diff which is readable by human. ex- 1 day 2 hours
```

You can refer [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/).

Hope this will help for you.

Answer (score 0):

I propose you the **DateInterval::format** function of php
like this:

```
$createddate = new DateTime('12-07-2020 12:10:01');
$approvedisapprovedate = new DateTime('16-07-2020 13:15:40');
        
$interval = $approvedisapprovedate->diff($createddate);

echo $interval->format('%a days %h hours %i minutes')."\n";
```

It goes back to this:

> 4 days 1 hours 5 minutes

I don't know the format of the date **$application['created_at']** and **$application['approved_at']** but I just put it there:

```
$createddate = new DateTime($application['created_at']);
$approvedisapprovedate = new DateTime($application['approved_at']);
        
$interval = $approvedisapprovedate->diff($createddate);

echo $interval->format('%a days %h hours %i minutes')."\n";
```

voici le lien de **DateInterval::format** :
https://www.php.net/manual/fr/dateinterval.format.php